# branch.io universal link does not work with test flight build

Tags: ios, testflight, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I've configured branch.io deep link and all options as explained at 
dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/overview/

I've setup corresponding configuration on the XCode side of things as well along with SDK integration as explained at https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/ios/

I've validated the universal link using the tool and script provided on the page at https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-linking-validator/

All tests run positive.

I'm also able to successfully launch the app from the deep link pasted in my Notes app, if I build and install in debug mode directly from XCode.

However once I distribute the build through test flight, I'm not able to launch the app successfully, it always takes me to App Store.

Comment: Maybe you are using development key?

Comment: Thanks for answering the question @SerhiiLondar. I reached out to branch.io support, and they say that the debugging cannot happen on test flight build or simulator. It's due to the IDFA that gets assigned differently on every install from test flight. They suggested as long as I can debug using XCode and validate the flow, it will work once in appstore. Marking this as answer, as I cannot post answer myself yet :(

Answer (score 3):

Your app should open and pass data whenever you click on a Branch deep link - regardless if you are testing on a Simulator, Device, or Testflight. The only issue Branch has with TestFlight is the way TestFlight handles the IDFA. TestFlight uses a fake IDFA which messes up how Branch recognize installs vs opens.

In my testing of Branch with TestFlight for Internal Testing:

```
√ opens background
√ opens terminated
√ data passed
√ Universal Links
√ URI Scheme
x install on first open (regardless of IDFA change)
```

If your app is not opening up in TestFlight, you might have a configuration issue. You want to make sure your [Branch Dashboard](https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/link) matches the [settings you have in your app](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/ios/).

Furthermore, you want to make sure your TestFlights testers are on the same [Development Team](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html). This is crucial for Apple Universal Linking to work.

Best,